# Is it possible to do a join with AWS Amplify DataStore query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, aws-amplify, datastore

I am using the AWS amplify SDK for javascript in my Vuejs web application.
In my amplify database, I have two tables: Hospitals and Doctors. There is a one to many relationship in my schema with one hospital to many doctors.

With graphql syntax, it is possible to run a join query that brings back all doctors in each hospital.

Is it possible to do the same with a DataStore query? We are using the AWS Amplify DataStore so that the application can run in offline mode.

```
query MyQuery {
  listHospitals {
    items {
      Doctors {
        items {
          firstName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```